# java android websocets dont give message

Tags: java, php, android, websocket

Can you help me?
When connecting and pinging the websock, the server sends a response, but when the second client connects, after sending the message, the entire client stack is zero, can you tell me what this is connected with?

```
use Workerman\Worker;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once "/var/www/html/DB/DB_connect.php";
require '/var/www/html/API/orders/orders.php';

$wsWorker = new Worker('websocket://0.0.0.0:27810');
$wsWorker->count = 4;
$users = [];

$wsWorker->onConnect = function ($connection) use (&$users) {
    echo "New connection \n";

};

$wsWorker->onMessage = function ($connection, $data) use ($wsWorker, &$users){
    
    $decode = json_decode($data);

    if(isset($decode->user)){
        if(!array_key_exists($decode->user, $users)) {
            $users[$decode->user] = $connection;
        }
    } elseif(isset($decode->ping)){
    var_dump($users);
        $webconnection = $users[$decode->ping];
   
        $webconnection->send('pong');
    
    } else {

    var_dump($users);
        foreach ($users as $key => $clientConnections){
        $clientConnections->send(json_encode("true"));
        echo "true \n";
        }
    }

   
};

$wsWorker->onClose = function ($connection) use (&$users){
    echo "Closed \n";
    $user = array_search($connection, $users);
    unset($users[$user]);
};

Worker::runAll();
```

client

```
private void connectToSocket() {
        URI uri;
        DBClass db = new DBClass();
        String hash = db.getHash(getContext());
        hash = hash + "HomeFragmentDriver";
        try {
            uri = new URI("ws"+"://"+"ip:27810");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e){
            Log.d("----uri------", e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        String finalHash = hash;
        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri, new Draft_17()) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Opened");
                mWebSocketClient.send("{ \"user\" : \""+ finalHash + "\"}");
                pingPong(finalHash);
            }
            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                Log.d("--mes--", s);
                if(s.equals("pong")) {
                    isPong = true;
                } else {
                    try {
                        socketCars(s);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }

        };
        try {
            mWebSocketClient.connectBlocking();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            mWebSocketClient.connect();
        }
    }
```

vpn - dont help
other websockets work
other libraries dont help
in logs writed "false" (websocetClient.getCOnnections().isConnectig())

edit
pong to go client